# Carrying previous value forward when missing value in SAS

Tags: loops, sas, missing-data

I have the following data set:

```
Player     Average1      Average2      Average3
001        .283          .             .302
002        .256          .             .
003        .314          .             .297
004        .282          .274          .
```

I would like the data set to look like the following:

```
Player     Average1      Average2      Average3
001        .283          .283          .302
002        .256          .256          .256
003        .314          .314          .297
004        .282          .274          .274
```

The table extends to Average24. I'm familiar with how to do this to one row in R with the dplyr package, but not with SAS.

R:

```
Data = DATA %>% mutate(Average2 = ifelse(is.na(Average2), Average1, Average2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this structure you could use an ARRAY.

```
data want;
  set have;
  array averages average1-average3 ;
  do _n_=2 to dim(averages);
    averages(_n_)=coalesce(averages(_n_),averages(_n_-1));
  end;
run;
```

It would be easier with a vertical structure.  Then you could use the `UPDATE` statement to implement a LOCF (Last Observation Carried Forward) operation.

```
data have ;
  input player @;
  do rep=1 to 3 ;
     input average @;
     output;
  end;
cards;
001        .283          .             .302
002        .256          .             .
003        .314          .             .297
004        .282          .274          .
;
data want;
  update have(obs=0) have;
  by player;
  output;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [coalesce](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lefunctionsref/63354/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1vjttz6nuankzn1gh4z3wgcu0bf.htm) function, it will assign the first non-missing value to the variable from the given list:

```
Average2=coalesce(Average1,Average2,Average3);
```

If you want, you can further use an array loop for all 24 variables, instead of writing manually